# How set format HH:mm

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

js:

```
$(".time").timeEntry({ show24Hours: true });
```

html:

```
<td>@Html.TextBox("TimeFrom", Model.TimeFrom.ToString(), new {@class = "time"})</td>
```

I see format HH:mm:ss, I need HH:mm

[image]

How do this?

browser IE9

I create test view:

```
@model DateTime
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.timeentry.css")"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.timeentry.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".time").timeEntry({ show24Hours: true, showSeconds: false });
    });
</script>
@Html.TextBox("TimeFrom", Model.ToString(), new { @class = "time" })
```

timeEntry comes into play only after the focus

I use http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html last version

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly turn it off? `showSeconds: false`

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$(".time").timeEntry({ show24Hours: true, showSeconds: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".time").timeEntry({ show24Hours: true, showSeconds: false });
```

according to the [docs](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html).. inside Quick Ref u can see

```
showSeconds: false, // True to show seconds as well, false for hours/minutes only
```

Comment: is there anything else your are doing there??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the format of initial textbox value?

```
@Html.TextBox("TimeFrom", Model.ToString("HH:mm"), new { @class = "time" })
```

It works for me.